# When element is updated twice JQ is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to send some data, but JQ animation/slideToggle etc. works only on last element (data1 and data2 won't toggle for example).

After reverse engineering/cut all non-related code/ modify it so it's simpler and better for understand, I got:

HTML:

```
                <div class="wrapper1">
                <div class="wrapper1_name">WRAPPER1</div>
                    <ul class="wrapper1_ul">
                        <li>
                            <div class="container1_name">container1</div>
                            <div class="container1"></div>
                            <div class="container2_name">container2</div>
                            <div class="container2"></div>
                            <div class="container3_name">container3</div>
                            <div class="container3"></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
<script src="jquery.min_v3.1.1.js"></script>
```

SOCKET.IO - server:

```
            socketio_data1_html = '<div class="data1">Data1</div>'
            req.io.emit('socketio data1', {socketio_data1_html : data1});

            socketio_data2_html = '<div class="data2">Data2</div>'
            req.io.emit('socketio data2', {socketio_data2_html : data2});

            socketio_data3_html = '<div class="data3">Data3</div>'
            req.io.emit('socketio data3', {socketio_data3_html : data3});
```

SOCKET.IO - client:

```
            /* DATA1 */
                socket.on('socketio data1', function(data1)
                {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('container1')[0].innerHTML +=
                    '<ul class="data1_ul"><u>Data1:</u>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data1_content">'
                                + '<li class="data1_li_content">' + data1.socketio_data1_html + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data1_info">Slide text (CLICK ME - why this is not working?):' 
                                + '<li class="data1_li_info">'
                                    + 'Data1 slideToogle text.'
                                + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                    + '</ul>';

                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('.data1_ul') !== null)
                    {
                        $('.data1_li_info').hide(); // optional - to hide INFO by default
                        $('.ul_data1_info').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.data1_li_info').slideToggle();
                        });
                    }
                });
            /* / DATA1 */

            /*  DATA2 */
                socket.on('socketio data2', function(data2)
                {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('container1')[0].innerHTML +=
                    '<ul class="data2_ul"><u>Data2:</u>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data2_content">'
                                + '<li class="data2_li_content">' + data2.socketio_data2_html + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data2_info">Slide text (CLICK ME - why this is not working?):' 
                                + '<li class="data2_li_info">'
                                    + 'Data2 slideToogle text.'
                                + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                    + '</ul>';

                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('.data2_ul') !== null)
                    {
                        $('.data2_li_info').hide(); // optional - to hide INFO by default
                        $('.ul_data2_info').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.data2_li_info').slideToggle();
                        });
                    }
                });
            /* / DATA2 */

            /* DATA3 */
                socket.on('socketio data3', function(data3)
                {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('container1')[0].innerHTML +=
                    '<ul class="data3_ul"><u>Data3:</u>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data3_content">'
                                + '<li class="data3_li_content">' + data3.socketio_data3_html + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data3_info">Slide text (CLICK ME - why only this works?):' 
                                + '<li class="data3_li_info">'
                                    + 'Data3 slideToogle text.'
                                + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                    + '</ul>';

                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('.data3_ul') !== null)
                    {
                        $('.data3_li_info').hide(); // optional - to hide INFO by default
                        $('.ul_data3_info').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.data3_li_info').slideToggle();
                        });
                    }
                });
            /* / DATA3 */
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper1
{padding:10px;
background:red;}

.wrapper1_name
{padding:10px;
background:brown;}

.container1_name
{padding:10px;
background:green;}

.container1
{padding:20px;
background:blue;}

.data1
{padding:10px;
background:orange;}

.data2
{padding:10px;
background:pink;}

.data3
{padding:10px;
background:aqua;}

.container2
{padding:20px;
background:violet;}

.container3
{padding:20px;
background:gray;}
```

Any idea WHY?

Comment: You need to show the code you're having a problem with.

Comment: @Barmar, ok, I will try to simplicity the code and paste it here.

Comment: It's really confusing mixing plain JS and jQUery like that. Why don't you use jQuery throughout?

Comment: Where in that code are you sending `<li>` elements like in the question?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML += '<ul>test + test.socketio + </ul>'; data is <li>test</li>

Comment: The function never uses the `test` variable that contains the data. In `<ul>test + test.socketio</ul>`, `test` is just part of the string, it's not expanded as a variable.

Comment: Did you mean to write `'<ul>test' + test.socketio + '</ul>'`?

Comment: @Barman yes, whole app is node.js + socketio app and it's hard to present it somewhere. I did add var data code, so you have better understanding of whats going on - but it's just simple passing html code (it can by anything). The problem is that JQ code for animation and toggling is not working, and I have no idea why.

Comment: @Barmar, after working on it I redefine original question. Thanks for your interest! Just let me know if everything is understandable or anything needs correction.

Comment: You assign to `socketio_data1_html` then you use `{socketio: data1}` in the `emit()` call. And in the receiver you use `data1.socketio_data1_html` instead of `data1.socketio`. These things all need to match.

Comment: You are right, now everything should be fine. But this is not the case here - on my localhost I have it set up correctly (socket send data successfully) but JQ is not working (I have striped code with all non-informative non-case integrated records). I can add app.js file so you can run it on you machine or I can send it to/use git/fiddle/codepen etc.  if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cause of flow of JS. By the time your third data socket.on pass, rest is outdated (cause you change html structure).

A simple working example is put all related JQ (your animation, slidetoggle and so on) in latest socket on data. Here:

```
socket.on('socketio data3', function(data3)
                {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('container1')[0].innerHTML +=
                    '<ul class="data3_ul"><u>Data3:</u>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data3_content">'
                                + '<li class="data3_li_content">' + data3.socketio_data3_html + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                        + '<li>'
                            + '<ul class="ul_data3_info">Slide text (CLICK ME - why only this works?):' 
                                + '<li class="data3_li_info">'
                                    + 'Data3 slideToogle text.'
                                + '</li>'
                            + '</ul>'
                        + '</li>'
                    + '</ul>';

                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('.data3_ul') !== null)
                    {
                        $('.data3_li_info').hide(); // optional - to hide INFO by default
                        $('.ul_data3_info').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.data3_li_info').slideToggle();
                        });
                    }

                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('.data2_ul') !== null)
                    {
                        $('.data2_li_info').hide(); // optional - to hide INFO by default
                        $('.ul_data2_info').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.data2_li_info').slideToggle();
                        });
                    }

                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('.data1_ul') !== null)
                    {
                        $('.data1_li_info').hide(); // optional - to hide INFO by default
                        $('.ul_data1_info').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.data1_li_info').slideToggle();
                        });
                    }

                });
```

This should work. Or you can put all JS/JQ related code in additional file and load it after all socket data is passed. The thing is, you need update html structure at first, THEN add JQ effects that makes use of it (html).